# Android widget HTTP request

Tags: android, http, post, widget, request

I recently started a weather widget where i can read data from my weather station.

I want the plugin to get the newest data from the weather station when onUpdate is called.
I know you need a Http request, but i know very little about it so if anyone can show me how to do it, i would really appreciate.

I already have a php script which outputs the data so I just need to get in on the widget and insert in in the TextView.

I already tried many scripts on the web, but i didn't know how to call the class when the plugin updates and so on ...

I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can send asynchronous http request with :

```
private void getHttpRequest(){
    AsyncHttpClient asyncClient = new AsyncHttpClient();

    asyncClient.get(YOUR_URL_STR , new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
        @Override
        public void onStart(){ 
        }

        @Override 
        public void onSuccess(String response){
             // here you will call an other method that sets the values
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable e,String response){

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish(){

    });
}
```

You can achieve that by downloading the [loopj library](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to do it without downloading any libraries? How do I implement the request in the widget activity so it will get called if onUpdate executes ?